# How to save column order and the width of the re-sized columns after changing the size of columns in NAT table into the prefernce

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, nattable

How to save Column order and width after changing their position and size ?

- re-sized column width should be persisted and used in the subsequent sessions (and also considered during export/import preferences usecase)
- any change in the column position should be persisted and used in the
  subsequent sessions (and also considered during export/import
  preferences usecase)

**Q1.** How can I get the column width of the nattable after changing the width by dragging/double click event ?
  - I want this with original column position even after the column is not in the original order.
**Q2.** How can I get the column order, after re-order using drag and drop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to Q1:
Ask the layers, they have `getWidth()` and `getColumnWidthByPosition(int)` methods

Answer to Q2:
Typically you will need to check the `ColumnReorderLayer` directly.

But if you want to store and load NatTable states, you should have a look at the persistence mechanism provided by NatTable. I wrote an [article](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTableStatePersistence/article.html) about this and it is even documented on the NatTable [website](https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=persistence).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Is it possible to restrict to save only Column order (ColumnReorderLayer) and Column/Row size (DataLayer)? I amd not interested to save other states like filter, freeze etc..

Comment: Either remove other information after gathering all states via saveState() or call saveState() explicitly only on what you want to save. There is no built-in mechanism to restrict this.